# How to jump to middle of buffer

Tags: cursor-motions

By pressing `gg` and `G` you can jump to both ends of a buffer.

`42G` jumps to the line 42.

Is there any quick `g` shortcut to jump to the middle of buffer. Something like roughly `round(number of lines/2)G` ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `N%` to jump to the Nth percent of the file. So e.g. `50%` jumps roughly to the middle of the buffer. See the help at `:h N%`

Answer (score 3):

I use these mappings in my own settings:

```
nnoremap <expr> M (line('$')/2).'G'
xnoremap <expr> M (line('$')/2).'G'
onoremap <expr> M (line('$')/2).'G'
```

It's pretty simple, it simply evaluates the expression `(line('$')/2).'G'` before running the mapping. `line('$')` is the number of the last line in the buffer, which we divide by two. Then the `.'G'` just appends 'G' to the resulting string.

If you like using the default `M` (Middle of visible screen), you could make this a leader mapping so that you don't overwrite it. For example:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>m (line('$')/2).'G'
xnoremap <expr> <leader>m (line('$')/2).'G'
onoremap <expr> <leader>m (line('$')/2).'G'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `N%` to jump to the Nth percent of the file. So e.g. `50%` jumps roughly to the middle of the buffer.

See the help at [`:h N%`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#N%25)

Comment: I edited the answer because it appeared in the "first post" queue to make it readable (the formatting was terrible) but I didn't see it is just a duplicate of Christian's answer.